# Finding a topological conjugacy of one-parameter quadratic families

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-dynamics

Let $f_c : z \rightarrow z^2 +c$ and $Q_a: x \rightarrow ax(1-x)$, I have to show that for $c \in [-2, \frac{1}{4}]$ there is an $a\in[1,4]$ such that $f_c$ is conjugate to $Q_a$

Unfortunately, I'm uncertain about how to proceed. My initial thought was to explore periodic or fixed points, given their preservation under conjugacy, but implementing this approach has proven challenging.

Is there a simpler method that can help identify such homeomorphisms more effectively?

Comment: Observe that the degree of both is the same, the first has no linear term, the second no constant term. So a linear function as conjugation map is a first obvious choice. If $z_n=Aw_n+B$, what does $w_{n+1}$ look like?